# 2d sprite did not rendered as original image after put in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: comparing in windows photo viewer and game windows unity]

image size = 2048 x 512px

as what shown on image i uploaded
I don't know what happened with my 2d sprite many people say that was compress problem but i still can't fix it and i tried to use unity asset store 2D pack its look good in my unity, someone ever got the same?
i used photo shop to make these 2D sprite, i used brushes, burn and dodge tools.

```
public GameObject background;
```

Comment: It looks like a Texture-Compression problem. I assume you are building for Android? 

Take a look [Here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44134/unity-android-truecolor-texture-performance-hit-and-alternatives-for-truecolor)

Comment: This is caused by reduced color space in the texture - maybe your bitness is too low (16-bit or 8-bit (256 color)) - what's the texture format in Unity? It's quite likely it's 16-bit instead of TrueColor.

Comment: Thank for the solution and yes, i build for android. i tried TrueColor in texture format setting it's worked although it increased the apk size near 1MB/texture, but one new question appear in my mind, why there are several image can look well without truecolor?  is possible because of the tools to make these texture?

Comment: Instead of TrueColor, use ETC if you don't have any alpha. Or if you do, use one of the supported alpha formats for your hardward. You may need to support multiple depending on your target platform. Or you can wait for Unity 5.1 which will support automatic rgb-alpha splits for sprites with ETC compression on Android.

Comment: That should have read "Unity 5.2". See http://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap